# What is the most simplest way to write callback library?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to write a function that received callback argument as string...
like

```
sum( 5 , "add_5" )
        // ^^^ as callback
```

I wrote some code like this...

```js
console.log(demo(5, "add_5"));

function demo(num, callback) {
  res = num;

  if (callback == "add_5") res = add_5(res);

  function add_5(res) {
    return res + 5;
  }
  return res;
}
```

But Is there any other but simplest or better way to write this code ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a string as a callback and how would that be a callback?

Comment: I am glad you asked. I answer your question below ! : - )

Comment: I want to learn something new.than how library work.like express or Third party module?

Comment: where you pass a string as argument...How that work...And How can I use this method In my libs?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
let result = demo(5, function add_5(res) {
    return res + 5;
})
console.log(result);

function demo(num, callback) {
    return callback(num);
}
```

This is passing a function as the callback (in this case it's a named function, but you could leave it anonymous). More on callbacks here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function.

Comment: No.I am writing a js  library .soo..every function should with in one function(main function)...Although How can you write your own function ? You may be not notice.I sayed library...